# Is this the right way to handle background thred?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsoperationqueue

I do a lot of request to the server:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [theRequest setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"]; 

     urlData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (urlConnection) 
    {
        finishedLoading = FALSE;
        while(!finishedLoading) {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        [delegate swHttpConnection:self withRequest:urlString failedWithError:nil];
    }
```

...When the request is done, I get a callback. However, If I use the code below, the selector won't get called:

```
- (void)request:(MBRequest *)request finished:(NSMutableArray *)resultArray
{
    //Handle resultArray data 

    [self performSelector:@selector(someRandomFunction) withObject: nil afterDelay:1.0f]; 
}
```

..but if I use the code below; It works fine:

```
- (void)request:(MBRequest *)request finished:(NSMutableArray *)resultArray
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0), ^(void) 
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) 
        {
            //Handle resultArray data 

            [self performSelector:@selector(someRandomFunction) withObject: nil afterDelay:1.0f]; 
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

So my question is twofold.

1. Is this the right way to do it? Do I need to force the callback to be run on the mainthred, or is the logic of the code wrong?
2. If I do have to force the callback to be ran on the mainthred, is the code above correct?

Also, the server request code crash sometimes at the:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

And I get this warning somethings:

```
Class _NSZombie_NSRunLoop is implemented in both ?? and ??
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pelase post the code of function "update"

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. The update function can be anything. Right now its just an empty function. I put an NSLog in it, and it never gets called

Comment: The "//Handle resultArray data" does it handle UI or some shared storage?

Comment: Yes, it updates the UI including a tableView, and update some local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you update the UI in this segment

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0), ^(void) 
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) 
        {
            //Handle resultArray data 

            [self performSelector:@selector(someRandomFunction) withObject: nil afterDelay:1.0f]; 
        }); 
    });
```

then it has to be called in the UI thread then yes you have to do it

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `NSURLConnectionDelegate` has a `request:finished:` method? and by looking at your code it seams as your using [MBRequest](https://github.com/mobiata/MBRequest). If so I strongly think you should have a look at their webpage for example how to do this using blocks.